# using ajax or php

Tags: php, jquery

i am making a photo gallery website. In that i need the newly added photos to be listed on top and there should be limited number of photos in a page. If the photos exceed their limit per page then the last one should automatically move on to the second page. What should i do for that. If u cannot understand my question you can take youtube comments as example. In that the last comment will be displayed first and the others will automatically move to the second page or u can view http://www.1channel.ch/ for example in that JUST ADDED section.

Comment: Youtube comments are stored in a database, and the query calls the first 10 entries DESC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is called *pagination*.

You can do it by sending a GET variable with the page you want to visit like this:

```
mysite.com/index.php?page=1
```

And in your code you do something like this:

```
// Set page 1 if it isn't specified
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1

mysql_connect( .. );
mysql_select_db( .. )

// SQL Query
$limit = 20;
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
$sql = "select * from my_table order by date desc limit $start, $limit";

// Get results
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// ...
```

You can search PHP pagination to find several examples and tutorials.

Comment: Thank u for u response Sheol. It helped me a lot.

Comment: How can i arrange the images like 3 or 4 columns and 20 rows per page leaving some space between images.

Comment: You can do that with HTML and CSS, in your PHP you will need something like this:
<div class="imagebox"><img src="<?php echo $img->src; ?>" /></div>
And in your CSS file: .imagebox { float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 8px; }